# Reading certificate error

Tags: java, certificate, base64, private-key

I am getting the following exception when running my application in a different server. The code works in two different tomcat servers, but on a specific one it doesn't work.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/bouncycastle/asn1/pkcs/PrivateKeyInfo
>     org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown
>   Source)   java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:372)

The part of the code when I am getting the error is the following on this line

**> pk = kf.generatePrivate(ks);**

```
 PrivateKey pk = null;        
    X509Certificate cert = null;

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
try{
    byte [] key = Base64.decodeBase64(llave.getBytes());
    byte [] cer = Base64.decodeBase64(certificado.getBytes());                              

    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key);
    pk = kf.generatePrivate(ks);
    pk.getEncoded();

    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(cer);
    cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);

    DateTime fechaDesde = new DateTime(cert.getNotBefore());
    DateTime fechaHasta = new DateTime(cert.getNotAfter());
```

Does somebody knows why this happens?

Comment: Yes, your runtime classpath does not contain the specified class.

Comment: Should I specify that on the classpath of my tomcat server?

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** This exception is thrown when JVM is unable to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.

[This link will help you](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

Comment: I added bouncycastle.jar to my classpath